# How to change content-type of a output Blob Stream?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a function that gets one blob, resizes it and the outputs it to another container.

```
  public static void Run(
            [BlobTrigger("test/{name}")] Stream image,
            string name,
            [Blob("test-tn/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall, ILogger log)
```

Yet, the generated image will always have a content-type of stream and I would like to define the content-type.

I've assumed I could output instead of a stream a CloudBlockBlob but I always get this error:

```
Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob
```

What can be the best way to define the content-type for the output of a BlobTrigger?

Comment: change your `FileAccess.Write` to `FileAccess.ReadWrite` then binding to CloudBlockBlob should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp#usage

Comment: @silent Even with ReadWrite had to rollback from Nuget Extensions.Storage 4.0.3 to 3.0.0 for it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root of your issue is that you are using outdated versions of the Storage nuget packages. See [here](https://github.com/sebader/azure-samples-collection/blob/master/AzureFunctions/SampleFunctions/Http2BlobFunction.cs) for a full example with Blob output:

`.csproj` file snippet:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.3" />
```

`Http2BlobFunction.cs`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

namespace SampleFunctions
{
    public static class Http2BlobFunction
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(Http2Blob))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Http2Blob(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            [Blob("myblobcontainer/{rand-guid}.txt", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlockBlob blob,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Received file upload request");
            var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(requestBody);
            return new OkObjectResult(blob.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end it looks like Functions 3.0 have this issue  Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.3 requires Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (>= 3.0.0 && < 3.1.0) but version Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 4.0.1 was resolved.